# Need a continuity LED for high voltage capacitive discharge rocket launcher

Tags: transistors, capacitor, high-voltage

I'm designing a capacitive discharge rocket launcher. The reason for the cap discharge is to ignite a series of many devices at once. I did not want to switch the HV with the momentary pushbuttons alone so I decided to drop down to 5v and use transistors. For simplicity I only show 4 buttons. I wanted to add continuity LEDs to show a connection to the firing ignitor and I've placed them in the schematic as shown, but this will not work with the transistor. I'm stumped and need some guidance.

Please note that this is a work in progress and some areas in the circuit still need brainstorming. I'm still relatively new to designing circuits so any help or suggestions with any part of the circuit would be appreciated. If something looks wrong, please tell me.
[image: capacitive discharge rocket launcher schematic]

[image: squib electric match technical information]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGeFVIJ2u0w

Comment: Yes, I'm still learning. Thank you. I will review your suggestion to improve my work.

Comment: Sigh. I was afraid of this. Now that you've posted your squib specs, I have to ask: why are you using 100 volts? Assuming perfect wiring (no voltage drop) you're looking at peak currents of 100 amps. On the one hand, it's hard to find transistors that will combine that current capability with 100 V operation. On the other hand, that peak current runs the risk of actually blowing the bridgewire before the pyro ignites. So, why are you using 100 volts?

Comment: Sometimes there is a need to ignite multiple squibs simultaneously. At an event several years ago we had 18 devices in the field that needed to be fired all at once. We used a hand-held blaster unit that charges a capacitor to about 200v. Don’t recall what the uF was but I remember calculating about 2 joules of output. The cable from the unit to squibs was 100ft. Although not always necessary, most of the time firing 8-10 devices is typical in show performances and it’s better to be further away, which means a longer cable run. Am I still going overboard with 100v?

Comment: I would appreciate any suggestions or feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Eeeek! I'll say that won't work.

1) Your LM311 needs to be powered from 12 volts. So does one set of resistive dividers into the LM311 (in order to set a reference to compare the divided 100 volts to), and so does the "Capacitor Ready" LED. Trust me, an LM311 output stage will not withstand 100 volts. Also, you need a fairly large resistor from the LM311 output to the + input, in order to introduce some hysteresis and get a clean "ready" transition.

2) Your high side switch transistor will not work with a 5 volt converter. The base must be driven higher than the emitter. In this case I suggest you use a 100 volt DC-DC converter with an inhibit input, and drive that.

3) Your low side switch transistor must handle at least 100 volts, and needs a base resistor to the key switch.

4) The 1N4005 will only work if the DC-DC converter has a current limit of less than 1 amp.

5) For the same reason as part 2, your firing transistors will never turn on, although their collector-base voltage rating is high enough that they won't burn out your debouncer. I suggest a topology like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLSOtn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You do not specify either your squib resistance or your peak firing current. Without these, the values of R2 and Q2 cannot be determined. Q2 must have a pulse current capacity equal to the peak firing current, which can probably be approximated as 100 / Rsquib. This will probably be a fairly hefty transistor - for instance, if your original circuit actually worked, the KHS50 only has a pulse current capability of 2 amps. To drive Q2, R2 needs to be about 10 times Rsquib. Not only that, since there is no way to guarantee how long some bozo will hold down the button, it will need to be rated for a lot of power, as it may have to withstand 100 volts indefinitely.

6) Your continuity LEDs need to be tied through high voltage diodes (1N4005s will work) directly to the squib drive lines. This will affect the current limit resistor values, as the extra diode drop needs to be taken into account. When the squib fires, the peak voltage, ~100 volts, will attempt to back-drive the LEDs, and this is A Bad Thing - hence the diode.

7) Finally, all your DC-DC converter - outputs need to be tied to ground.

There may well be other problems, but that will get you started.

Comment: Eeeek is right. I have a long way to go. I was never too comfortable with the LM311 full cap indicator idea. I may just keep it simple and use an NE2. I'm trying to wrap my head around your suggested transistor topology.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Aw, you noticed. It should be "about 10 times Rsquib" and I've fixed it in the answer. This way, the base drive for Q2 is about 1/10 the squib current, insuring that Q2 is saturated.

Comment: @JohnnyHolguin - No, the LM311 idea is fine. It just needs a tweak. And a neon indicator is NOT a great idea. I'd even go so far as to say it is very bad. I mean, really bad.http://www.chml.com/products/pdf/5-4.pdf says the worst case turn-on voltage for an NE2 is 90 volts. So a capacitor only charged to 89 volts might not cause the NE2 to light. You wanna bet the squib wouldn't fire at that voltage?

Comment: Posted squib technical info. Your schematic is using an NPN and a PNP transistor. The KSH50 is not the switch anymore. I'm still trying to understand and guess that this arrangement serves to protect the debouncer.